How to timeout concurrent calls when iterating through a list of items
I was looking into a problem where I need to process a bunch of items in a list. Now I need only the results from the items which can be processed in the configured time, and other results need to be discarded. I wrote this program and a very simple version of it worked, but scaling up the logic, I got stuck because either the switch case "all done" is always executed, or "timeout" is executed but still gives all results.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func doSomething(x int) int {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    return x
}

func main() {
    timeoutCfg := 5

    done := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    somethings := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    results := make(chan int, 10) // buffered channel to hold partial results
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // Launch goroutines to process tasks
    for _, key := range somethings {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(k int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            results <- doSomething(k)
        }(key)
    }

    // Start the timer
    timer := time.After(time.Second * time.Duration(timeoutCfg))

    // Wait for all goroutines to finish or for timeout
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(done)
        close(results)
    }()

    select {
    case <-timer:
        fmt.Println("timeout")
        for x := range results {
            fmt.Println(x)
        }
    case <-done:
        fmt.Println("done")
        for x := range results {
            fmt.Println(x)
        }
    }
}


You're not closing results until after all goroutines complete, so your timeout case still waits for all results. Read values from results as they're ready, there's no need to wait on done, and you are already closing results to signal completion.

Ok, write synchronous code first:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func doSomething(ctx context.Context, x int) (int, error) {
    timer := time.NewTimer(700 * time.Millisecond)
    defer timer.Stop()

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done(): // canceled
        return 0, ctx.Err()

    case <-timer.C:
    }

    return x, nil
}

func process(ctx context.Context, timeout time.Duration, somethings []int) ([]int, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, timeout)
    defer cancel()

    var results []int
    var err error
    for _, key := range somethings {
        var result int
        result, err = doSomething(ctx, key)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        results = append(results, result)
    }

    if err != nil && !errors.Is(err, context.DeadlineExceeded) {
        return nil, err
    }

    return results, nil
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    timeoutCfg := 5 * time.Second
    somethings := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

    results, err := process(ctx, timeoutCfg, somethings)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        for _, x := range results {
            fmt.Println(x)
        }
    }
}

Try in on the Go Playground. Here I use a context.Context for cancelation and break the loop on the first error.
When the first error is not context.DeadlineExceeded the error is returned, otherwise the (partial) result. When you need more info (whether the result is complete), an additional bool would be in order.
Great, that works so far, let's make process concurrent:
func process(ctx context.Context, timeout time.Duration, somethings []int) ([]int, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, timeout)
    defer cancel()

    eg, ctx := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)

    var results resultCollector
    for _, key := range somethings {
        eg.Go(func() error {
            result, err := doSomething(ctx, key)
            if err == nil {
                results.append(result)
            }
            return err
        })
    }

    err := eg.Wait()
    if err != nil && !errors.Is(err, context.DeadlineExceeded) {
        return nil, err
    }

    return results.get(), nil
}

We are using golang.org/x/sync/errgroup here, and we need a thread safe append, so let's write a resultCollector:
type resultCollector struct {
    results []int
    mu      sync.Mutex
}

func (r *resultCollector) append(x int) {
    r.mu.Lock()
    defer r.mu.Unlock()
    r.results = append(r.results, x)
}

func (r *resultCollector) get() []int {
    r.mu.Lock()
    defer r.mu.Unlock()
    results := r.results
    r.results = nil
    return results
}

Try in on the Go Playground. The trick is to prefer synchronous functions and use context.Context for cancelation.
You could also use channels in the resultCollector if you like, see Summarizer for an example this is just a matter of taste.
